# CSS fixed nav on top, when opened covers full screen, can't scroll

Tags: css, navigation, scroll, fixed

I have a mobile navigation bar set to fixed using CSS at the top of my page so it sticks upon scrolling. When clicked, the full navigation menu is revealed and on many devices it covers the entire screen (which is what I want), but the last 25% or so of it is below the fold. Since the menu is set to fixed, it will not allow scrolling down (when open) to view the hidden content below the fold.

Basically, how do I make a fixed element scrollable once it is open and part of it is being hidden below the fold? I know the problem is that the top of the element is still attached to the top of the screen, just not how to make it temporarily "switch" over to an absolute position (which will allow the scrolling down) when the full menu opens.

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated! This is driving me nuts...

Comment: can you post ur codes here or fiddle it?

Comment: @Kris Pipitone, were you able to figure this out? I've run into the same issue.

Comment: No. I found out it was impossible with the menu script that I was using, so I simply switched to another one that slides in from the left side.